# Jenkins meven Java Import working giving differnt path

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, import

I have a a java class looking for another project using an import.

```
 import this.is.the.java.file.im.looking.for
```

I run off a pom.xml file using a maven build in eclipse and it's working fine using the m2e plugin. When i try to run it on jenkins using the maven integration plugin it says it can't find the file because it's looking into the same project folder instead of the dependency project.

Comment: can you be bit more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven configured on jenkins also requires appropriate settings.xml to fetch dependencies it required. There might be possibility that due to inappropriate settings.xml file , maven won't be able to fetch dependencies.

Please make sure settings.xml at in jenkins installation directory e.g. /var/lib/jenkins for ubuntu.

also check whether settings.xml under .m2 folder in your jenkins installation directory.

and finally validate whether there is jar file fetched in local maven repository under .m2 directory.

Comment: So I'm running on linux and the folder /var/lib/jenkins/ exists but its empty. All the files I'm currently working with are under /webdata/jenkins/

Comment: keep settings.xml under /webdata/jenkins and specify the path of settings.xml in jenkins configuration. For that, go to the 'Build' Section of the job and click "Advanced". There is a 'Settings File' option there. Specify the location your 'settings.xml' file.